# react-datepicker css selected range

Tags: css, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am implementing: react-datepicker: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
My expected: [image: expected]

But, when I change start-date and end-date, I changed border-radius for start-date and end-date, and this is my result: [image: result]

Link to try: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snow-sm2z62?file=/src/App.js

My problem is: doesn't have background around `start-date` and `end-date`[image: propblem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I fixed my problem by added `::before` and `::after` to `start-date` and `end-date`.

```
.react-datepicker__day--range-end::before,
.react-datepicker__day--range-start::before {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  background-color: #222 !important;
}

.react-datepicker__day--range-start::after {
  width: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  background-color: #e3f762 !important;
}

.react-datepicker__day--range-end::after {
  width: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0 !important;
  background-color: #e3f762 !important;
}
```

Finally, I custom `DatePicker` day by added `renderDayContents` props to custom date display:

```
<DatePicker
    onChange={onChange}
    startDate={startDate}
    endDate={endDate}
    selectsRange
    selectsDisabledDaysInRange
    renderDayContents={(day) => <span>{day}</span>}
    inline
/>
```

And style for day content:

```
.react-datepicker__day--range-end span,
.react-datepicker__day--range-start span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  color: #e3f762 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the background color on start and end dates you have to overwrite the default CSS which is getting applied by the react date picker library
You can try using this CSS in your global CSS file

```
.react-datepicker__day--range-end, .react-datepicker__day--range-start {
        border-radius: 50% !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: #e3f762 !important;
        border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the !important from the CSS which you don't want to overwrite